# Big difference in timing between dependencies call and request call

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

in my application I notice in production some delays every now and then and makes me less happy with the user experience.

Now in application insights loggin i found this pattern:

- dependency call from microservice A to B take 4 seconde
- the request call in microservice B takes couple of microseconds

the request call is always almost in the middle of the dependency call; so let say 2 seconds after the dependecy call is done the request is shows; and two seconds afterwards.

No i know you cant fully trust these numbers but on the otherhand bit stuck with debugging.

We are using Azure Kubernetes Services and first i was thinking we got hit by a DNS bug. Since the two second delay. But I would rule that now out as the request is also having the 2 second delay afterwards.

Any advice how to continue?

Comment: What is you application tech stack (dotnet, java etc.)? There might be issue also with http client or how you are using.

Comment: C# with .net core 3.1. We are always using the HttpClientFactory

Comment: Ok. So, what endpoint you use when let's say microservice A calls B? Is it like https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#namespaces-and-dns ?

Comment: i use the full url; so i suspect it goes via the ingress back in; also tried to hit the kubernetes service directly via the <servicename>.<namespace>.service.cluster.local but experience the same problem

Comment: Can you share code snippet of one slow http call in the question please

Comment: we fixed it... It is this bug: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1326 and the work around with dnsConfig didnt work for use because we used alpine images. we switched to the regular .net images and applied the work around. Problem gone

Comment: Great! Can you post it as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we fixed it... It is/was this bug: github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1326 and the work around with dnsConfig

Initially it didnt work for use because we used alpine images. we switched to the regular .net images and applied the work around. Problem gone